# Need a function to continue decreasing a value once it runs out of valid values

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, controls, call

So Im writing a function that is supposed to count up all the first N even numbers in an array where the user picks N. Which is fine, however if there are fewer than N even numbers in the array, then the function should just add them all which is the part I am having difficulty with.

function call:

```
cout << "The sum of the first " << userSum << " even numbers is: " <<
SumEvens(list, SIZE, userSum) << endl;
```

function definition:

```
int SumEvens(int arr[], const int size, int evensAdd)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0 && arr[i] != 0){//if the number is even and not 0 then that number is         added to the sum
            evensAdd--;
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        if(evensAdd == 0)//once evensAdd = 0(N as previously mentioned) then the function will return the sum
            return sum;
    }   
}
```

So for example if I have an array: `{1,2,3,4,5}`

and ask for it to calculate the sum of the first 2 even numbers it would output 6

however if i ask for it to calculate say the first 3 or 4 or 5 even numbers it will output that the sum is 6

why would it subtract one?

Comment: I'd recommend using `std::vector<int>`, to pick up the results.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer that helped you so other users will see right away what solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you finish the for loop before `evensAdd` reaches 0, you never reach the `return sum` statement and therefore not set the return value of the function. The value returned is then just a random number read from the stack. This is just a technical stuff, the correct approach should look like this:

```
int SumEvens(int arr[], const int size, int evensAdd)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0 && arr[i] != 0)
        {
            evensAdd--;
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        if (evensAdd == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Using `break` will immediately jump to the end of the `for` loop and the return value will be set if in all cases.

EDIT: Check your compiler warnings, I'm pretty sure that every compiler gives a "Control may reach end of non-void function".

Answer (score 0):

```
int SumEvens(int arr[], const int size, int evensAdd)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size && evensAdd > 0; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0 && arr[i] != 0)
        {
            evensAdd--;
            sum += arr[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This will work but like @πάντα ῥεῖ said using `vectors` would be a better idea.
You can just stop the loop with set condition, which is in this case better style than `break`ing.

[Working example!](http://ideone.com/Gxw6rr)

Comment: +1 for not using a `break` statement to add an extra condition to the for loop